# Try/Except in for loop failing

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, try-catch

I am trying to catch some exceptions when processing files from an AWS s3 bucket. I know that the processing works just fine normally, as the error i get is expected and generated by myself by altering the column names of 1 file. The bucket contains several files that should process like normal, while the 1 file i altered should throw an exception. My desire is to append the filename to a list if it is not processed, print the exception with logging module, and continue processing the rest of the files. This is my code:

```
for item in settings.keys:
    try:
        response = settings.client.get_object(Bucket=settings.source_bucket, Key=item)
        tmp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()), encoding='unicode_escape', sep=None, engine='python')
        tmp['account_number'] = item.split('/')[4][:-4]
        tmp.columns = tmp.columns.str.strip()
        tmp.columns = tmp.columns.map(settings._config['balances']['columns'])
        df = pd.concat([df, tmp], ignore_index=False)
    except:
        settings.unprocessed.append(item)
        logger.exception(f'{item} Not Processed')
```

Before i altered the 1 file, everything processed like it should. By using try/except, i want to catch the exception if a file contains errors, and still process the rest of the files. However, after i altered the 1 file, every single file in the bucket threw an exception, and nothing was processed. Does anyone have any input as to why this happens?

```
2023-01-25  14:59:56 - ERROR - xxxx.csv Not Processed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\Python\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx.py", line 19, in balances
    df = pd.concat([df, tmp], ignore_index=False)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\Python\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\Python\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 360, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\Python\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 591, in get_result
    indexers[ax] = obj_labels.get_indexer(new_labels)
  File "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxx\Python\xxxx\xxxx\xxxx\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3721, in get_indexer
    raise InvalidIndexError(self._requires_unique_msg)
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
    raise ValueError("cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels")
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

UPDATE:

I did the same for some other files, and this works as expected. The error i generated is catched and printed to console, and the filename is appended to a list. This is the working code that does as expected:

```
for item in settings.keys:
    try:
        tmp = pd.DataFrame()
        response = settings.client.get_object(Bucket=settings.source_bucket, Key=item)
        if item.endswith('.csv'):
            tmp = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()), encoding='unicode_escape', sep=None, engine='python')
        elif item.endswith('.xlsx'):
            tmp = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(response['Body'].read()))
        tmp['file'] = item.split('/')[4]
        tmp.columns = tmp.columns.map(settings._config['account statements']['columns'])
        tmp['row'] = tmp.index + 2
        tmp.columns = tmp.columns.astype(str)
        tmp.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())

        for col in tmp.columns:
            if col.startswith('Beløp'):
                settings.statement_currencies[item.split('/')[-1:][0]] = col[-3:]
                tmp[col] = tmp[col].astype(str)
                tmp[col] = tmp[col].str.replace(',', '.')
                tmp[col] = tmp[col].astype(float)
                tmp['direction'] = np.where(tmp[col] > 0, 'Incoming', 'Outgoing')
        df = pd.concat([df, tmp], ignore_index=False)
    except:
        settings.unprocessed.append(item)
        logger.exception(f'{item} Not Processed')
```

Comment: A good starting point would be to print the exception

Comment: Updated with the exception. As mentioned the exception itself is expected, as i generated it by purpose

Comment: Well, is that the error you expect to see, or another?

Comment: It is the error i expect to see, as i changed the column names, so reindexing would not work. The files are processing as they should when the the generated error is removed, so my issue is just that the exception on the 1 file is not catched, but now every file throws an exception for some reason.

Comment: @pyth0nEiken So what is the exception?